# .Net Publishing Database Project and Import Fails

Tags: .net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I am attempting to switch over a database from sql server version 12.0.5203 to 14.0.1000, however I am seeing issues. While I can't get a backup to import, I also can't get the project to publish to a blank database. When I run the DB publish I very quickly get an error stating:

> "Unable to connect to master or target server [database_name]. You
>   must have a user with the same password in master or target server
>   [database_name]."

With this same project I have published 100's of times to the older version of the database.

So with the publish issue aside. I tried to export data tier application and import with the newer version of sql server and every time I do that I get the following errors on the import.

> Could not import package. Warning SQL72012: The object
>   [itss_tutor_3_Data] exists in the target, but it will not be dropped
>   even though you selected the 'Generate drop statements for objects
>   that are in the target database but that are not in the source' check
>   box. Warning SQL72012: The object [itss_tutor_3_Log] exists in the
>   target, but it will not be dropped even though you selected the
>   'Generate drop statements for objects that are in the target database
>   but that are not in the source' check box. Error SQL72014: .Net
>   SqlClient Data Provider: Msg 15404, Level 16, State 19, Line 1 Could
>   not obtain information about Windows NT group/user
>   'PSLLC\dbodenschatz', error code 0x54b. Error SQL72045: Script
>   execution error.  The executed script: CREATE ASSEMBLY [GroupConcat]
>       AUTHORIZATION [dbo]
>       FROM 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
>   (Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac)

So basically I can't import an existing database and I can't publish to an empty one. Yet I can publish fine to the older version.

UPDATE: 
I installed newer version of Sql Server Data Tools and restarted. Now the publish doesn't fail immmediately but instead I get this error:

> Creating [GroupConcat]... (65,1): SQL72014: .Net SqlClient Data
>   Provider: Msg 10343, Level 14, State 1, Line 1 CREATE or ALTER
>   ASSEMBLY for assembly 'GroupConcat' with the SAFE or EXTERNAL_ACCESS
>   option failed because the 'clr strict security' option of sp_configure
>   is set to 1. Microsoft recommends that you sign the assembly with a
>   certificate or asymmetric key that has a corresponding login with
>   UNSAFE ASSEMBLY permission. Alternatively, you can trust the assembly
>   using sp_add_trusted_assembly. (65,0): SQL72045: Script execution
>   error.  The executed script: CREATE ASSEMBLY [GroupConcat]
>       AUTHORIZATION [dbo]
>       FROM 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
>   An error occurred while the batch was being executed.

Answer (score 0):

The data tools install as well as following this link seems to have both the publish and import working:

https://www.sqlshack.com/impact-clr-strict-security-configuration-setting-sql-server-2017/